# SQL: Make colors from color-table searchable

Tags: mysql, sql, colors, sqlconnection

I have a database with cards of different colors.

A Card can be "**Colorless**" or one or more colors:
"**Red**","**Green**","**White**","**Blue**","**Black**"

The **cards** is in a **Card table** with **id, name** and some other card info,

and the **colors** is in a **Color table** with **name**(ex:"Red"), a color **code**(ex:"r") and a color **id**

And there are a **Connection table** with **card_id** and **color_id**

So **the question is** how do a **make colors searchable**?

I like to be able to find all card that are **"only Red"**,
aswell as all cards that are **"Red or Blue"**,
and all cards that are **"Red and Blue"** (and the same for 3,4 and 5 colors!)

There are 30 different combinations of color:

```
//000001//000010//000011//000100//000101//000110//000111
//001000//001001//001010//001011//001100//001101//001111
//010000//010001//010010//010011//010100//010101//010110
//010111//011000//011001//011010//011011//011100//011101
//011111
//100000 (Colorless)
```

I have found out that this is posible with **UNION** but
one have to make all 30 different combinations and then UNION them all together!

```
SELECT 
c.id
'false' AS Colors,
'true' AS Red, 
'false' AS Blue
'false' AS Green
'false' AS White
'false' AS Black
'false' AS Colorless
FROM cards_data AS c
INNER JOIN con_cards_colors AS ccc_red ON c.id = ccc_red.cards_id
INNER JOIN colors AS co_red ON co_red.id = ccc_red.colors_id
WHERE
    co_red.name = "Red"

Union
(...)
```

This dosnt seem like a good solution!

**So any idears will be appreciated?**

(Optimal I like some kind of a SQL View..)

Comment: In my opinion "colorless" shouldn't be a color, but the absence of colors. Otherwise it would be possible to make a card both colorless and red for instance.

Comment: #Thorsten: I do agree, it is just the way the database is made right now, because the cards comes from a JSON representation where it has Colorless..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use conditional aggregations here. For Red and Blue for example you want to find cards where

1. both colors exist
2. no other color exists

That means if I count Red and Blue for a card I must get 2. If I count all colors I must also get 2. (Same for one, three or more colors.)

So use this query and only change the colors mentioned and the number of colors:

```
select *
from cards_data where id in
(
  select cards_id
  from con_cards_colors
  group by cards_id
  having count(case when colors_id in (select id from colors where name in ('Red','Blue')) then 1 end) = 2 -- i.e. find all
  and count(*) = 2 -- i.e. find only those and no others
);
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed the CASE keyword. I've edited my answer.

Comment: It seems that this way off getting the id dosnt work well then you need more then one parameter. It takes like 2min to get a result(in my Mysql database), and sometime it never give one when I try to UNION two Selection, like Color and Type? Is there a better way then using UNION?

Comment: Please describe this problem more properly. `Type` would be in what table? And what would be sample criteria? Such as: look for red-and-blue cards of type 'big'?

Comment: Yes sorry :-) I would like to be able to load cards that are "red" and "blue" and have the cardtype "creature" and cardsubtype "wizard" and "human". I tried to make 3 copy of the "select cards_id(...)" and UNION them together, but as I wrote, it will sometimes give me a result after a couple of minutes, but most time no result.

Comment: Okay. Again: what table does the cardtype reside in? And in what table is the cardsubtype? Is it like the colors: The card must both be "wizard" and "human" an nothing more? (So as to neither get a wizard dwarf nor a human wizard-thief?)

Comment: Yes, like the color table, there are a cardtype table and a con_cards_cartypes connection table, and there are a cardsubtype table and a con_cards_cardsubtype connection table. A card can have 0+ colors, 1+ cardtypes and 0+ cardsuptypes and there are other subtables like rarity and other stuff ordered in tables in the same way. I would like to be able to get both a version where it is a "wizard-human"(nothing else) and a version with "wizard" and "human" where it can be other subtypes also. (Just like the color serach).

Comment: You can more or less copy from the colors subquery: `where id in (select cards_id from con_cards_colors ...) and id in (select cards_id from con_cards_cardsubtype ...)`. If you have problems with this, I suggest you open a new request where you show exact table structures and sample content, maybe even use sqlfiddle.com. Such requests usually get much attention and quick answers.

Comment: Thank again, that seems to work. I just thought, that I should UNION them together, but simple making an AND in the condition seems to work fast.

Comment: Do remember set theory in maths? You want to *reduce* your result set by limiting it to certain card types. UNION, however, *adds* two sets together. The *union* of cards with the right color and the cards with the right type would be the cards with either the right color or the right type. It is INTERSECT you are looking for. The *intersection* of cards with the right color and the cards with the right type would be the cards with the right color *and* type. MySQL doesn't support the INTERSECT keyword however.

Answer (score 0):

Here what it is probably a bad solution. :)
Pivoting cards and colors as a derived table to query it later as a CTE.

```
--CREATING TABLES 

CREATE TABLE [card] (
    cardID int,
    Name varchar(255),
);

CREATE TABLE color (
    colorID int,
    Name varchar(255),
    );

CREATE TABLE colorcard (
colorID int,
cardID int,);

insert into card (cardID,Name)
values 
(1,'CARDa'),
(2,'CARDb'),
(3,'CARDc')



insert into color (colorID,Name)
values 
(1,'Red'),
(2,'Green'),
(3,'White')

insert into colorcard (colorID,cardID)
values 
(1,1),
(2,1),
(3,2),
(3,3),
(1,3)

-- SHOWING TABLES 

select * from card

select * from color

select card.name,color.name,color.colorid 
from card
    join colorcard on card.cardid = colorcard.cardid
    join color on colorcard.colorid = color.colorid;

-------------------------------QUERY

with cte as (
select cardname, 
    coalesce (red/red,0) as red , 
    coalesce (green/green,0) as green, 
    coalesce (white/white,0) as white,
    ':)' AS [Where is set to CardIsOnlyWhite] -- Comment this out 

from 
    (
    select 
        card.name as cardname
        ,color.name as colorname
        ,color.colorid as colorid
    from card
        join colorcard on card.cardid = colorcard.cardid
        join color on colorcard.colorid = color.colorid
    --where color.name = 'red'  
    ) as colorcard
PIVOT  
(  
AVG(colorid)  
FOR colorname IN (red, green, white)  
) AS PivotTable
)
select *
from cte 

--where cte.white   = 1 ,   -- CARDS WITH WHITE, may or may not have other colors.

where                       -- CARDS WITH ONLY WHITE
        cte.white   = 1 
    and cte.red     = 0
    and cte.green   = 0
  



--DELETE EXERCISE 

truncate TABLE colorcard
truncate TABLE color
truncate TABLE [card]

Drop TABLE colorcard
Drop TABLE color
drop TABLE [card]
```