# Core Data: Matching a combination of multiple items in a to-many relation

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

*EDIT: Forgot to mention that I filter out cards with unwanted colors in Swift code afterwards.*

So, this is yet another question regarding to-many relationships in Core Data and how to write a predicate for it. In short, I'd like to match a combination of multiple items in a to-many relation.

#### Setup

1. **Color table** with five colors: Red, Green, White, Black, Blue
2. **Card table**, each card has a to-many relation to color table

#### Goal

Search for cards with black **and/or** white color, meaning:

1. Card may be **black only**
2. Card may be **white only**
3. Card may be **both black and white**

#### So far

Best results are (simplified):

```
NSPredicate(format: "ANY color == Black") // Only black cards, good
NSPredicate(format: "ANY color == White") // Only white cards, good
NSPredicate(format: "ANY color == Black OR ANY color == White") // Only black AND white cards, bad
```

There is a very similar post that concerns MySQL here, in case it helps further clarifying the issue:

[SQL: Make colors from color-table searchable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920494/sql-make-colors-from-color-table-searchable)

Comment: `NSPredicate(format: "color IN %@, ["Black", "White"])`?

Comment: Tried `IN` as well, no difference. :/

Comment: How many objects in the Card entity?

Comment: Approx. 15 000 - 20 000 objects.

Comment: NSPredicate(format: “SUBQUERY(color, $C, $C == Black OR $C == White).@count > 0”)

Comment: @pbasdf Well, that actually worked, at least partly. I did the above, plus added another one for the unwanted colors. Then combined them with a `NSCompoundPredicate` ("and"-variant)!

Comment: @Joneth Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment by [@pbasdf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3985749/pbasdf) I came up with the following solution (with better syntax in actual code):

`// Desired colors
let includePredicate = NSPredicate(format: “SUBQUERY(color, $C, $C == 'Black' OR $C == 'White').@count > 0”)`

`// Undesired colors
let excludePredicate = NSPredicate(format: “SUBQUERY(color, $C, $C == 'Green' OR $C == 'Red' OR $C == 'Blue').@count == 0”)`

`// Combined to one predicate
let finalPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [includePredicate, excludePredicate]`